# Distribution of a function of Discrete Uniform RVs

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ take the values ${0,1,...,N}$ with probability $\frac{1}{N+1}$. What is the PMF of $|X-Y|$?

I started it like so:
Let $|X-Y| = Z$

$P(Z<z) = P(-z < X-Y<z)$

In the continuous case, I'd just integrate the joint over the domain. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to translate that strategy to the discrete case.

Comment: Are X and Y independent? If so, I'd rewrite  {|X-Y| = n} in Terms of possible values of X and Y. Then you can use the distribution of X and Y.

Comment: yes they are independant. I can sort of figure this problem out actually if I think a little bit and use some numbers. but what I'm trying to learn is a general way of approaching a problem like this. (e.g. Suppose X and Y are geometric, then what?)